# Django caching CSS (?)

Tags: python, html, css, django

I currently have this template

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% load staticfiles %} <!-- New line -->

<html>
    <head>
        <title>GingerBites</title>


    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/styles.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
</body>
</html>
```

**settings.py**

```
ACTUAL_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(ACTUAL_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)
```

For some reason when running my app locally my css is served correctly, but on page refresh my css remains the same after I save changes and refresh my page. I think something is caching my css. Although when I remove the `link` to my css, all my css styling disappears. Does anyone know how I can change this?

Or why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turns out the issue is that static files should be called like so:

```
{% static /path/to/static %}
```

So in your case:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static css/styles.css %}"/>
```

Django documents it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/).

Comment: Set your STATIC_URL and such in `settings.py`, rather than in index.html.

Comment: It is. Check the bold text above.

Comment: Sorry but it was in the index.html code. Go to your CSS manually when you view source. Refresh it there and see if it has been modified.

Comment: Look at the index.html page and right click "View Source". Then from there, open what ever this link: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/styles.css"/>` directs you to. From there, make a change and 1) see if the CSS has actually changed on refresh 2) if the URL is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83814/discussion-between-will-campbell-and-theamateurdataanalyst).